# How to plot correct best fit line?

Tags: least-squares, linear-regression

I'm working on a software where I'm plotting graphs and finding **best fit** line.
I have used Least-Square Method and linear regression technique with **y = mx + c**

My problem is that when most of the X values of graph are equal (not all) at that time best fit line is not proper but when there is good variation it seems correct.

Following pictures are for reference, Orange line is graph and Green is best fit (please don't consider other grey lines)

[1. points with variation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOQ5R.png)
[2. most X values are equal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEuMQ.png)

What is the problem here I'm not getting? please help.

Comment: When most $x$ values are equal, your model $y=mx+c$ doesn't make sense, as $x$ is quasi constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fitting $x=m y + c$ instead.

Alternatively, if your $x$ and $y$ axis have the same units, try minimizing the [perpendicular offsets](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPerpendicularOffsets.html) (i.e. the euclidean distance between the point and the line) as opposed to the vertical offsets (as in standard least-squares fitting).

Comment: alternative solution worked for  me thanks

Comment: My above problem is solved but I got into another issue. When graph is more horizontal i.e. most of the y value are equal this solution fails. Is there any other way or I miss something.

Comment: $y=m x + c$ cannot describe lines that are parallel to the $y$ axis. $x=m y + c$ cannot describe lines that are parallel to the $x$ axis. Least squares fitting, as it is usually formulated, is not capable of doing both: see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124532/least-squares-equation-for-a-vertical-line) or [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57685/line-of-best-fit-linear-regression-over-vertical-line). If you want something that works in both cases, try [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).

Comment: Thanks @Wouter, but will you please explain it in simple language. As I'm not very good in mathematics

Answer (score 0):

The problem has horrific conditioning.

What is the slope$-$intercept equation for a vertical line?

The value for the slope is swinging between $\pm \infty$. This mean a very small perturbation in your data can cause an enormous change in the results.

The trial function is 
$$
 y(x) = a_{0} + a_{1} x. 
$$
The data will consist of a sequence of measurements $\left\{ x_{k}, y_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{m}.$
The linear system is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} a  &= y \\
%
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 \mathbf{1} & x
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 a_{0} \\ a_{1}
\end{array} \right]
%
&=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 y
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$
The normal equations are
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} a  &= \mathbf{A}^{*} y \\
%
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 \mathbf{1} \cdot \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{1} \cdot x \\
 x \cdot \mathbf{1} & x \cdot x
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 a_{0} \\ a_{1}
\end{array} \right]
%
&=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{1} \cdot y \\
 x \cdot y
\end{array} \right].
%
\end{align}
$$
The solution for the normal equations is
$$
\begin{align}
  a &= \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*} y \\
%
&=
%
\left(
 \det \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right)
\right)^{-1}
%
\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
 x \cdot x & -\mathbf{1} \cdot x \\
 -\mathbf{1} \cdot x & \mathbf{1} \cdot \mathbf{1}
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{1} \cdot y \\
 x \cdot y
\end{array} \right].
%
\end{align}
$$
Isolate the slope
$$
  a_{1} = \frac{
\left( \mathbf{1} \cdot \mathbf{1} \right)
\left( x \cdot y \right) - 
\left( \mathbf{1} \cdot x  \right)
\left( \mathbf{1} \cdot y \right)} 
{
\left( \mathbf{1} \cdot \mathbf{1} \right)
\left( x \cdot x \right) - 
\left( \mathbf{1} \cdot x  \right)^{2}
}
$$
Consider the case where $\hat{x}_{k} = \bar{x} + \epsilon_{k}$, where $\epsilon_{k}<<\bar{x}$ for all $k$. The perturbations have mean $0$. The terms in the denominator have this behavior:
$$
\begin{align}
\left( \mathbf{1} \cdot \mathbf{1} \right)
\left( \hat{x} \cdot \hat{x} \right) - 
\left( \mathbf{1} \cdot \hat{x}  \right)^{2}
&\to
m\left( \sum x_{k}^{2} + \sum x_{k} \epsilon_{k} \right)
 - 
\sum x_{k}^{2} + 2 m \bar{x}^{2} \\
&\to
2 m \sum x_{k} \epsilon_{k} - 2 \sum x_{k} \sum \epsilon_{k} \\
&\to
0
\end{align}
$$

@Wouter offers a path to salvation by rotating the coordinate system.